# disabling "treat warning as errors" in WDK

Tags: c, driver, wdk

I'm building a printer driver using the Build utility of the WDK. I need to turn off "Treat warnings as errors". It is turned off in the Visual Studio project file but that apparently doesn't affect Build.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by the MSC_WARNING_LEVEL directive in the SOURCES file:

MSC_WARNING_LEVEL=/W4 /WX

Remove the /WX to stop treating warnings as errors. However, current industry practice is to compile with /W4 /WX, so I suggest simply getting used to fixing the warnings.